# JFrame Singleton

Tags: java, swing, jframe, singleton

I have implemented a singleton design pattern in one my application classes. That class is called SearchFounisseurUi. It inhierits the JFrame Swing class. I have also another class which calls the SearchFounisseurUi class. I have written the code below but it is not working for me. Here is my code so far.

```
package VIEW;

import CONTROLLER.SearchFournisseurController;
import MODEL.tableModel.FournisseurTableModel;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.ScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SearchFounisseurUi extends JFrame{

// Fields
private JTextField nomFournisseur ; 
private JTable resultTable ; 

// Label
private JLabel lblNomFournisseur; 

private JButton chercherButton ; 

// Model view controller 
private FournisseurTableModel fournisseurTableModel ; 
private SearchFournisseurController searchFournisseurController;
// Singleton
private static SearchFounisseurUi instance=null;

private  void SearchFounisseurUi() {

    initComponents();
    buildFrame();
    eventHandling( );
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();

}





/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                SearchFounisseurUi frame = SearchFounisseurUi.getInstance();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void initComponents() { 
    // Model 
    fournisseurTableModel = new FournisseurTableModel();

    searchFournisseurController = new SearchFournisseurController() ;
    searchFournisseurController.setModel(fournisseurTableModel);
    searchFournisseurController.setUi(this);
    searchFournisseurController.setData();

    // View
    lblNomFournisseur = new JLabel("Nom Fournisseur");        
    nomFournisseur = new JTextField(40);
    chercherButton = new JButton("Chercher");
    resultTable  = new JTable(fournisseurTableModel);

 }

private void eventHandling() {
 }

private void buildFrame() {
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
     setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,400));
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

            // Line 1 
    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 0;
            gc.gridwidth = 2;
            gc.weighty = 1.0;
            gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

            add(new JScrollPane(resultTable),gc);

            // line 2

            gc.gridy++;
            gc.gridwidth  = 1 ;
            gc.weighty = 0.01;
            gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            add(lblNomFournisseur,gc);

            gc.gridx++;
            add(nomFournisseur,gc);

            // line 3

            gc.gridx = 0 ;
            gc.gridy++ ; 
            add(chercherButton,gc);


 }

public static SearchFounisseurUi getInstance(){
    if(instance == null)
    instance =  new SearchFounisseurUi();  

    return instance;

}
}
```

and here is where I initiated the class:

```
btnChercherFournisseur.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                SearchFounisseurUi fen  = SearchFounisseurUi.getInstance();

            }
        });
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you're having?

Comment: the SearchFounisseurUi(Frame) not showing up

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `setVisible(true)` on the `SearchFounisseurUi` object.
That should solve your problem.

```
    btnChercherFournisseur.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            SearchFounisseurUi fen  = SearchFounisseurUi.getInstance();
            fen.setVisible(true);  /// !!! /// 
        }
    });
```

Comment: No no, see OP's constructor. Frame would be visible but again there wont be anything displayed in there.

Comment: the error was on both SearchFounisseurUi constructeur, and setVisible() method

Answer (score 0):

Constructor doesnt have [return](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) type. So from

```
private  void SearchFounisseurUi() {
```

change it to

```
private SearchFounisseurUi() {
```

And similar to your main method, in your getInstance method call

```
instance.setVisible(true);
```